# How to modify a deserialized object

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON string as follows

```
string str = "{"Id":["1799"],"Type":1,"Date":null,"Group":null,"Ids":1799}";
```

I want to covert it to the following format

```
{"Id":1799,"Type":1,"Date":null,"Group":null }
```

In short I want to remove the "Ids" and convert "Id" value to string.

For this I tried deserializing this string as follows-

```
object yourOjbect = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(str);
```

But here I am stuck. How Can I remove/change a value from this object.
I tried converting this object to array and list but could not find remove/modify option in it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the JSON framework for .NET from http://www.newtonsoft.com/json (also available as a nuget package)

Then you can use the following to Deserialize into your object

```
string str = "{"Id":["1799"],"Type":1,"Date":null,"Group":null,"Ids":1799}";
MyObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

Then maybe create a different object for your output, and have a constructor that will accept the original object as input, and then serialise it to Json.  The constructor must then do any internal conversions/changes that you require.

```
OtherObject other = new OtherObject(myObj);  //Create new object from original.  
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(other);
```

Answer (score 1):

Expando Object.

```
string str = "{"Id":["1799"],"Type":1,"Date":null,"Group":null,"Ids":1799}";
```

Initially, deserialize the json using NewtonJson lib

```
dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(str);
Dynamic newStr = new ExpandoObject();
newStr.Id = parsedJson.Id.ToString();
newStr.Type = parsedJson.Type;
...
```

then serilize the newStr:

```
str newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newStr);
```

Output :
`{"Id":1799,"Type":1,"Date":null,"Group":null` }

Comment: Is there any way we can use c# libraries to do this?

Comment: C# library could help only to serialize/deserialize the json string.